# Passenger nginx with HTTP/2 ALPN support on CentOS 7

Tags: nginx, openssl, centos, passenger, http2

I installed passenger-modded version of nginx following [this guide](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/el7/).

Unfortunately the version of nginx in the RPM was built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e which does not provide HTTP/2 ALPN support. Is building nginx from source my only option to enable HTTP/2 in this configuration?

Comment: Yes, or you can install docker and pull a docker container and get any nginx version or a prebuilt image with RPM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a few options:

1. Install from source with OpenSSL also built from source.
2. Use Docker or other container technology to run this.
3. Upgrade to Centos 7.4 ([literally just released](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2017-September/022532.html) at time of writing) as this includes OpenSSL 1.0.2 [which includes ALPN support](https://ma.ttias.be/rhel-centos-7-4-restores-http2-functionality-nginx/).
4. Use a CDN in front of your server so they provide the HTTP/2 support and you can stay on HTTP/1 for now. [Cloudflare offer free plans for this](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/) for example.
5. Similar to above, put another server/load balancer in front of Nginx which supports HTTP/2 and proxies requests to Nginx.

Comment: Ad 3. I did the upgrade already yesterday, but it doesn't affect the configuration in any way, since nginx coming from the RPM is compiled using the older version of OpenSSL.

Comment: Ok, but at least makes 1) easier (only have to install nginx from source rather than nginx and openssl). And imagine this will change shortly - as I say Centos 7.4 has literally just come out.

Comment: But still good to know. Haven't upgraded myself yet but do plan on it soon!